# Differ REST from XML-RPC by WSDL

Tags: rest, soap, wsdl, xml-rpc

Here is the WSDL - http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?WSDL

I see bindings for Soap 1.1 & 1.2, and 2 others, to retrieve data via HTTP get & post.
I want to know if the last 2 stand for REST or XML-RPC.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean these lines:

```
<wsdl:port name="GlobalWeatherHttpGet" binding="tns:GlobalWeatherHttpGet">
  <http:address location="http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="GlobalWeatherHttpPost" binding="tns:GlobalWeatherHttpPost">
  <http:address location="http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
```

These are part of the WSDL document. [From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language):

> Defines the address or connection point to a Web service. It is typically represented by a simple HTTP URL string.

They have nothing to do with REST or XML-RPC which are not defined by a WSDL document.

Comment: Here they say that it's possible - https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restwsdl/

Comment: But is this approach, which was describe in 2008(!) used? I don't know of any usage of WSDL for REST in real life.